# Is "With which" correct?

Tags: prepositions, pronouns, collocations

I've been using "With which" many times but, days ago, an app corrected this structure. Then, what's  grammatical or preferable?

> With which book should I start?

or

> which book should i read first?

Are other recommendable expressions?  Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is correct. Pay little attention to automated grammar corrections.

> With which book should I start?
>
> Which book should I start with?

Both are correct, the former being the more formal of the two.